# MultiAutoCompleteTextView does not honor keyboard NEXT

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext, textview

I am using a MultiAutoCompleteTextView and it seems to work okay with the following exeception: With the focus in the MultiAutoCompleteTextView, hitting the 'NEXT' key on the soft keyboard does NOT move the focus to the next field which is an EditView. Is there a known issue with this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting the net result here for the record -- this was discussed in an "office hours" chat outside of SO.

Ron's `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` looked like:

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView  
            android:id="@+id/etCreateMessageTo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint=""
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners"
        />
```

He was taking the default for `android:imeOptions` and seeing this behavior. I suggested he explicitly add `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`, and it turns out that does the trick.

Comment: A big thanks to Mark on this. Regular EditText controls work fine without specifying the imeOptions=actionNext. The MultiAutoCompleteTextView seems to require it!